# Remote Validation not working

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm triying to make work remote validation in ASP MVC3. I spended some hours reading and trying it, but i didn't achieve it.

First of all ... I've added this lines to appSettings in Web.config file

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

Then, I make a class with dataanotations.

```
Public Class PackageCreationInfo

    'Lot of Properties here...
    <DisplayName("Id Modalidad")>
    <Remote("ModeExists", "PreactivatedLicenses", AdditionalFields:="IdVersion")>
    Public Property IdMode As Integer
    <Required(ErrorMessage:="La Versión es obligatoria")>
    <DisplayName("Id Versión")>
    Public Property IdVersion As Integer

End Class
```

In my view I added this scripts

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And I've this ones in my _layout

```
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.datepick-es.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Plugins/Expander/expand.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then, In my controller, I've this function

```
 Public Function ModeExists(ByVal IdMode As Integer, IdVersion As Integer) As JsonResult

            Dim ExistModeForThisVersion As Boolean = _ProductApps.ExistModeForVersion(IdMode, 13)

            If (ExistModeForThisVersion) Then
                Return Json(String.Format("Esta modalidad no está disponible en la versión seleccionada."), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
            Else
                Return Json(True, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
            End If

        End Function
```

My problem is that I can't get this function called.
The facts is that the generated HTML don't have a data-val-remote attribute or something like it.

Other client validations that are not "remote" are working propertly.
What could be the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry... I made a stupid mistake (another one)

I will write here my mistake as a penitence because there is *remote* posibility that It helps to someone.

In my View... I wrote

```
 @Html.DropDownList("IdProgramMode", New SelectList(ViewBag.ProductModesList, "Id", "Mode"))
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.IdMode)
```

But It should be

```
 @Html.DropDownList("IdMode", New SelectList(ViewBag.ProductModesList, "Id", "Mode"))
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.IdMode)
```

It's important that the name of the field match the name of the property. Otherways nothing will happens.